# owin self-host with windows authentication - AllowAnonymous not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin, windows-authentication

I've enabled Windows authentication [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32080694/webapi-with-owin-selfhost-and-windows-authentication)

It all works fine, there's just a tiny issue: Doing so makes every controller method protected by windows authentication. NO problem I thought, just use the [AllowAnonymous] adorner on the few controller methods where anonymous access is okay, but that won't work.

Is there any way to get the self-host to not authorized every method on every controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to enable Windows auth *and* anonymous auth.  [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.authenticationschemes(v=vs.110).aspx).  As is, you have told Owin to require Windows auth and disallow anything else.

In the code you cited, you would change this:

```
listener.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.IntegratedWindowsAuthentication 
                               | AuthenticationSchemes.Anonymous;
```

Comment: Not only does this work, it also enables the [Authorize] flag to work as expected so I can now freely decide which controllers / controller methods should authorize and which should not.